# Best way to handle complex scenario in form with multiple submit and search

Tags: php, forms

I would like to ask help on how and what is the best way to handle this kind of scenario, for me its too complex. maybe example is highly appreciated.

the page that i want to build should have this features.

1. can be open in browser via http://server/view.php?id=1000
2. if id=1000 does not exist, post a message not exist and throw it to another page
3. if id=1000 does exist, then open the page for viewing
4. the page has a form with with a textbox where i can add info about the records
5. the form submit to itself and process the data to DB.

how can i combine all these since features? i really appreciate if a sample snippet code especially on the form submit, checking if id exist thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very basic example below. You can fill in the details

```
$id = intval($_GET['id']);  // assume it's int and force to be int

// do database call
// 1. init connection, set db, etc
mysql_query("select something from something where id = ".$id);

// check for results
if (! results exist) http_redirect('your error page');

// Now check if any posted variables exist
if (isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field=2']) .... 
{
   1. validate your data
   2. insert to the database
   3. http_redirect to success page
}

// if you're getting here, that means id is valid and data has not been posted
 show your form
 display whatever HTML you need with the data loaded for id above
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, i have question on it. So the form will always be in the lower part of the code? can i also replace 
if (isset($_POST['SUBMIT']) then validate data, insert then load the form again by itself? I don't need to http_redirect on success coz i want in one page only. thanks

Comment: yes, you can do validation, insert, and the load if you want to stay on the same page. You might want to add a little message at the top to let the user know that Save was successful or not. Also, yes, the form has to be at the bottom. You have to check first for valid id and post data and then display what you want